# Dialogs between users in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, message

How to make similar dialogues between users in iOS as shown in the picture. Should I use just for this ScrollView and Labels or I can using some standart way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create it. here is a nice tut that creates a chat bubble. take a look at his work and you'll see how it can be done. http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/

also here is the link to a github project that could be useful for you. https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView

alex has done a great job explaining everything, so this might be what you are looking for.